# How to check if 'Per-node memory binding' is supported in any libvirt version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm, libvirt

I am using kvm and getting an error: unsupported configuration: Per-node memory binding is not supported with this QEMU

I have the #virsh version:

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.9
Using library: libvirt 1.2.9
Using API: QEMU 1.2.9
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.0.0
```

on host 
 # uname -a

```
Linux nfv 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

# lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

When I try to start the instance it fails with error (#virsh start SomeOSOS-30-5-0-0_rls_743):

```
   error: Failed to start domain AlteonOS-30-5-0-0_rls_743
   error: unsupported configuration: Per-node memory binding is not supported with this QEMU
```

**I am trying to find any abbilty to check if the libvirt+QEMU are supporting this option.**

It's xml:
 #virsh dumpxml SomeOSOS-30-5-0-0_rls_743

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>SomeOSOS-30-5-0-0_rls_743</name>
  <uuid>c0eac6f0-e519-459d-978d-bd5b2da0be45</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>33554432</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>33554432</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <cputune>
    <vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='2'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='2' cpuset='4'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='3' cpuset='6'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='4' cpuset='1'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='5' cpuset='3'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='6' cpuset='5'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='7' cpuset='7'/>
  </cputune>
  <numatune>
    <memory mode='strict' nodeset='0-1'/>
    <memnode cellid='0' mode='strict' nodeset='0'/>
    <memnode cellid='1' mode='strict' nodeset='1'/>
  </numatune>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Westmere</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdpe1gb'/>
    <numa>
      <cell id='0' cpus='0,1,2,3' memory='16777216'/>
      <cell id='1' cpus='4,5,6,7' memory='16777216'/>
    </numa>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/SomeOSOS-30-5-0-0_rls_743.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:4b:e8:9b'/>
      <source bridge='mgmt'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <rom bar='off'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x42' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <rom bar='off'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Regards.

Comment: What's the output of "ldd /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86* | grep numa"

Comment: ldd /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86* | grep numa;echo $?
1

Comment: $ ldd /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86* | grep numa
 libnuma.so.1 => /lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f5953144000)

Comment: There isn't this library.